# Securing uber webhook not working

Tags: node.js, cryptography, uber-api

For some reason I can't make this work

```
require crypto = require('crypto')

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'clientSecret')
const hash = hmac.update(JSON.stringify(req.body)).digest('hex')

if (hash !== req.header('X-Uber-Signature')) {
   return res.json('something is wrong ' + hash + ' ' + req.header('X-Uber-Signature'))
}

return res.json('you got in!')
```

I'm following the instruction here https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/webhooks#security

but hash is generating different value

Other approaches are welcome too.

Comment: What's the value that you expect and what did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Uber send json with spaces before keys and values. Like this

```
{"event_id": "...", "resource_href": "...", "meta": {"status": "...", "rider_id": "...", "user_id": "...", "resource_id": "..."}, "event_type": "...", "event_time": ...}
```

You can do this before activating boryparser. And create hex from this data

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

let data = "";
req.on('data', function(chunk){data += chunk});
req.on('end', function(){
    req.jsonBody = JSON.parse(data);
    req.rawBody = data;
    req.originalUberReq = data;
});
next();
});
```

then

```
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
.update(req.originalUberReq)
.digest('hex');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working implementation in Python to validate a webhook:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

# Compute hmac sha256 signature from payload + client secret
digester = hmac.new(
    UBER_CLIENT_SECRET,
    request.data,
    hashlib.sha256
)

# Parse json post data
event = request.get_json(force=True)

# Validate webhook signature for our app
if request.headers.get('X-Uber-Signature') == digester.hexdigest():
    pass
```

Comment: How does this solve the question? It's a node.js question!